# Requests will not refresh data with refresh function

Tags: python, python-requests

I created a function to refresh requests to cataas (cats as a service) API.
The only problem is is that it does send the correct json data, but the problem is is that the data wont refresh even though I redefined them in a function. I am using the requests module.
Here is my code snippet:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://cataas.com/cat?json=true')
data = r.text
json = json.loads(data)
def refresh_data(): #The function that will not work
    r = requests.get('https://cataas.com/cat?json=true')
    data = r.text
#The code thats apart of one of my functions
if command == '!cat':
             chat = open("chat.txt", "a")
             chat.write(f"Replcord (bot): Meow  <br> <img src='https://cataas.com{json['url']} ' width='100' height='100' />' <br> \n") #does return data but still sends the same thing
             refresh_data() #Runs the function
             chat.close()
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the scope on which you are updating the variable.
You would need to set data and json as global.

But that would be very ugly code rather use returns like this:

```
import requests
import json

def refresh_data():
    r = requests.get('https://cataas.com/cat?json=true')
    data = r.text
    return data

if command == '!cat':
    chat = open("chat.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
    data = refresh_data()
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    chat.write(
        f"Replcord (bot): Meow  <br> <img src='https://cataas.com{json_data['url']} ' width='100' height='100' />' <br> \n")
    chat.close()
```

Comment: Your solution Has the following error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'json' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Have you checked that json is impoted?

Comment: Yes the only problem is is that I cant use it in the function so any alternatives to this or a solution to use it in functions?

Comment: Actually I solved this on my own, thanks for helping